# Putting powerpc 476 in spin loop in uboot

Tags: linux, powerpc, u-boot, smp

I have two core PPC476 on my SOC. 
On one core I am able to run linux kernel.

Can anyone suggest me how I can put 2nd core in spin loop in uboot and later bring it out and map it into the linux kernel.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the following specifications:
https://www.power.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Power_ePAPR_APPROVED_v1.1.pdf

And refer to IBM currituck as a reference platform in Linux kernel.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Hrishikesh